# Learning a SVM with Bag of features

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

Hello I try to learn a SVM with a Dataset of negative and positive examples.
Iam using the Kmeans Clustering and Bag of Words for it. 
My steps are:

1. compute the descriptors and key points for each image with surf
2. put all descriptors in one mat (unclustered mat) and create the label mat(1 and -1)
3. using K-Means for clustering put in the unclustered mat and run the algorithm the result is the vocabulary
4. start the Bag of features procedure with BowImgDescriptorExtractor using the  FlannBasedMatcher and the Surf detector for it
5. set the extracted vocabulary to BowImgDescriptorExtractor
6. compute bow with img, imgkeypoints
7. the result is a bow descriptor
8. train the SVM with the bowdescritpor and the labels

The syntax is correct, but if I use svm->islearned the svm returns false.
Something in my procedure is wrong. Please give me some advice what Iam doing wrong

Comment: You would need to show us some code and data.
I would start between step 7 and 8. 
How do you convert the bow descriptor into training data for the SVM?

Comment: What is your final target?! you want to match two images? or find a specific region in one image? or what?